# Getting unwanted base64 when require('image.dir')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, require

I have a project structure with two separate folders, one for the backend and the other one for the frontend.
I'm trying to generate PDFs with an image inside comming from the public file of the frontend.
I'm getting it with my actual image path put into a require('').

```
    getImagesRequire(state) {
        state.images.forEach( el => {
            el.src = require(`@/assets/${el.dir}`)
        })
        return state.images;
    }
```

It's working perfectly for all images in that list but one, when that original path is sent through the require('') it's returning the base64 code of the image, and I don't understand where it's coming from. I'm thinking maybe it comes from the file but it's png like every other image file... Any insight welcome

Comment: You're using something like Webpack too?  You're winding up with something like `el.src=blahblahblah==`?  If so, that's what's supposed to happen...  if you want to just get something like `el.src=/assets/something/something.png` then you need to build it as a string (instead of `require`) and put the image in the public folder.

Comment: Most of the time I get that blahblahblah which is the public path I guess and is what I want, but one picture returns the picture base64 encoded. I'm not doing anything different from the other pictures, I changed the file and it still returns the new image in base64. It's really weird...

Comment: It's some config to disable that webpack functionality I think

Comment: I think it might be filesize related.  If you delete the one acting funny, copy one that isn't acting funny and naming that copy the same thing as the one you deleted, does it start behaving like you'd think again?  Seems like it might be related to:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077663/why-webpack-converts-requirepath-to-img-png-in-base64

Comment: It was this indeed, I had that same conclusion but for 5ko. Thanks a lot